# Elastic Search Keyword search on a text field does not return results

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following mapping for my index.

```
    {
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "author": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "book_name": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The following are the documents that are indexed.

```
  [
  {
    "author": "Conan Doyale",
    "book_name": "Sherlock Holmes"
  },
  {
    "author": "Arabian Nights",
    "book_name": "Arabian Night"
  },
  {
    "author": "Bride and Prejeduice",
    "book_name": "Gurnindher Chadda"
  },
  {
    "author": "Pride and Prejeduice",
    "book_name": "Jane Austen"
  },
  {
    "author": "Ashwin Sanghi",
    "book_name": "Krishna Key"
  },
  {
    "author": "Ashwin Sanghi",
    "book_name": "Krishna lock"
  },
  {
    "author": "Arabian Night",
    "book_name": "Arabian Night"
  }
]
```

Now, If I query the author field using fieldname.keyword, it does not return a result.

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "author.keyword": "Arabian Night"
    }
  }
}
```

My understanding is that it would return the following document

```
{
    "author": "Arabian Night",
    "book_name": "Arabian Night"
  }
```

Also, the following term query also did not return any result.
I would expect some results for the same.

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "author": "Arabian"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> If I query the author field using fieldname.keyword, it does not
>   return a result.

This happens because the subfield named `keyword` doesn't exist. For the above to work the mapping should have been:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "author": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "book_name": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So update your mapping and re-index the documents again.

> Also, the following term query also did not return any result. I would
>   expect some results for the same.

In the term query you are querying on the field `author` whose type is `text`. By default a `text` type field uses [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html). So `Arabian Night` will be indexed as two terms `arabian` and `night`. Notice that change in case. The standard analyzer changes the case of all terms to lowercase when indexing. Therefore term query will not match `Arabian` but will match `arabian`. So the below term query will work:

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "author": "arabian"
    }
  }
}
```